# Respond to all WiFi probe requests with ESP8266?

Tags: esp8266, c++, wifi

I'm wondering if there's a way to program an ESP8266 such that it responds to all WiFi beacon probe requests. For example, if a device sends a probe request for a WiFi network name, e.g. "homewifi", the ESP8266 will send a response frame to that and have that device connect to it. Is this possible to do?